# MS Access Database and ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-desktop, ms-access

I would like to create an MS Database which is updated in real time with tabular data. The data should be processed automatically so that farmers are able to log in into the database and see charts and maps of information, and also feed in data from their fields.
The MS Database should automatically link to ArcGIS once the information is ready for spatial analysis and visualization.

What would be the most viable way to automate data processing in MS Access and also automate real time map creation in ArcGIS?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do nothing more than display XY locations held in an Access table then you simply add a link to the table and create an XY Event layer.

If you want Access to take control of ArcMap and do something, for example do a query in Access and fire this off as a selection on a layer in Arcmap then you are looking at development scenario using Automation. I posted some sample code [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/62483/how-to-access-and-send-coordinates-from-third-party-application-to-the-current-r/62486#62486) but would recommend you trawl the [geonet](https://geonet.esri.com/welcome) website as what you are asking is something that many people have wanted to do over the years.